# Oracle query with every minute a day

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I want to write a query in oracle sql, which returns every minute of the current day in one column. But i've got no idea, how to start :-(

```
min
27.03.2014 00:00
27.03.2014 00:01
27.03.2014 00:02
...
27.03.2014 23:59
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a table, that contains these values?

Comment: @Alexander No, a `select min from tab_times where trunc(min,'dd')=trunc(sysdate,'dd')` is not quite difficult :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use arithmetic to manipulate dates, and the simple CONNECT BY trick to generate a stream of rows.

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'
/

with cte as ( select trunc(sysdate) as start_date from dual )
select start_date + ((level-1)/(24*60)) as date_w_mins
from cte
connect by level <= (24*60)
/
```

Comment: Thanks! I also thought of `connect by` but I found no point to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numtodsinterval` function and is simple too:

```
SELECT to_char(TRUNC(sysdate)+ 
               numtodsinterval (level-1,'minute'),'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') min
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (24*60);
```

Comment: Thanks, is this query "better" (for Performance, CPU, whatever) than APC's query posted just before yours? "Explain" is not use usefull for this simple query.

Comment: don't worry , both query's plan are same. I gave numtodsinterval function's usage:)..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date + minute FROM
(
SELECT TO_DATE('yyyy.mm.dd', '2014.03.27') date FROM DUAL
CROSS JOIN
( 
SELECT 0 minute FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT rownum r
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY rownum <= 1439
) T
) TT
```