# Oracle query to fetch every minute between two timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I need a oracle query which returns every minute between given two timestamps. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680617/oracle-query-with-every-minute-a-day) Stack Overflow question.
Can we improve the same query?

Comment: I prefer to have a permanent [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html). This article is based on SQL Server, but the concept is the same in any DBMS.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov No, you do not need a static table for such requirement. You just need to have the start and end datetime, and the rest is a simple hierarchical query producing the required rows, typically known as [**Row Generator**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/).

Comment: @LalitKumarB, I'm not saying that you **need** a permanent table. You can generate it on the fly, as you've shown, or you can have it on disk. I prefer to have it on disk. It is useful in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the minutes between two datetime elements using [**Row Generator**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/) technique, you need to convert the difference between the dates into the **number of minutes**. Rest remains same in the **CONNECT BY** clause.

For example, to get all the minutes between `11/09/2015 11:00:00` and `11/09/2015 11:15:00`:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT to_date('11/09/2015 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date_start,
  3      to_date('11/09/2015 11:15:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date_end
  4    FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT TO_CHAR(date_start+(LEVEL -1)/(24*60), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') the_date
  7  FROM DATA
  8    CONNECT BY level <= (date_end - date_start)*(24*60) +1
  9  /

THE_DATE
-------------------
11/09/2015 11:00:00
11/09/2015 11:01:00
11/09/2015 11:02:00
11/09/2015 11:03:00
11/09/2015 11:04:00
11/09/2015 11:05:00
11/09/2015 11:06:00
11/09/2015 11:07:00
11/09/2015 11:08:00
11/09/2015 11:09:00
11/09/2015 11:10:00
11/09/2015 11:11:00
11/09/2015 11:12:00
11/09/2015 11:13:00
11/09/2015 11:14:00
11/09/2015 11:15:00

16 rows selected.
```

Above, `CONNECT BY level <= (date_end - date_start)*(24*60) +1` means that we are generating rows as many as the number `(date_end - date_start)*(24*60) +1`. You get `16` rows, because it includes both the **start** **and** end window for the minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The other answers are also correct but I prefer this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create like this if you want all minutes from sysdate to 15 NOV:

```
SELECT to_char(TRUNC(sysdate) + numtodsinterval(level - 1, 'minute'),
               'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') min
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
           (trunc((TO_DATE('16-NOV-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')) - sysdate) * 24 * 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use below and give your values instead of systimestamp and systimestamp+1

```
 select (systimestamp)+level/(24*60) as Rang_values
    from
    dual
    connect by level
    <=
    (
    select extract( minute from diff)+
    extract(day from diff)*24*60 +
    extract(hour from diff)*60 as diff
     from
    ( 
    select systimestamp+1-systimestamp diff from dual
    )
    )
```